# Why do I get parameter conversion not allowed error in the code below?

Tags: mql4, quantitative-finance

I have this simple code below. I keep getting "'test_Array' - parameter conversion not allowed" error on the iBandsOnArray line. The array works fine in other functions.  Can someone help me? thx

```
void OnStart()
  {
      int test_Array[5];
      ArrayInitialize(test_Array,0);

      test_Array[0] = 1;
      test_Array[1] = 2;
      test_Array[2] = 3;
      test_Array[3] = 4;
      test_Array[4] = 5;

      Alert(test_Array[2]);

      double SD;

      SD = iBandsOnArray(test_Array, 0, 5, 2, 0, MODE_UPPER, 0);

      Alert(SD);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`iBandsOnArray` takes an array of doubles as parameter, you are passing an array of ints.

Documentation: https://docs.mql4.com/indicators/ibandsonarray